# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\oficina\init.php on line 111

Tags: php

Seguinte pessoal, primeiro vou explicar minha situação:

Eu tenho um arquivo chamado lib.php que tem várias funções e classes, e carrego ele em todo arquivo php.

Nesse arquivo tenho a função body(), que eu chamo logo depois da tag `<body>` em todo arquivo, ele retorna o html de um cabeçalho e chama o arquivo init.php, que faz o seguinte:

1. dentro dele tem um array com uma lista de todos os arquivos dentro da pasta do projeto
2. pega essa lista e verifica se falta algum arquivo
3. escaneia todas as pastas e subpastas e verifica se existe algum arquivo que não foi listado

Porém, tem também  um array que contém as pastas que não é pra escanear.
Até ai tudo beleza, eu testei inúmeras vezes esse arquivo acessando ele diretamente, causei alguns erros propositais e ele detectou legal, jogou o log na tela, etc, isso acessando http://.../init.php

Porém, quando eu chamo esse arquivo dentro da função body() do arquivo lib.php, ele dá um erro muito estranho:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\wamp\www\oficina\init.php on line 111

aqui vai o código do body() em lib.php:

```
function body(){
    $return = '';
    if(file_exists('init.php')){
        require 'init.php';
    }else{
        $return .= '<b>
            <font color="red">
                SISTEMA DE DETECÇÃO DE ERROS COMPROMETIDO!
            </font>
        </b>
        <br />
        Detectado por function body() em lib.php';
    }
    // resto da função
    return $return; // ele imprime esse retorno usando echo body();
}
```

aqui vai o código que ta dando erro em init.php:

```
$list   = array(); //lista de arquivos
$list[] = 'C:/wamp/www/oficina/img/bt_Lembrete.png';
$list[] = 'C:/wamp/www/oficina/img/bt_lembreteNew.png'; // muitos outros arquivos

$noScann    = array(); // pastas para não escanear
$noScann[]  = 'C:/wamp/www/oficina/noScann';
$noScann[]  = 'C:/wamp/www/oficina/js/lib/ui';
$noScann[]  = '.';
$noScann[]  = '..';

function scan($dir){
    global $noScann;
    var_dump($noScann); // VAR_DUMP ******************
    $files = array();
    $d = dir($dir);
    while(($entry = $d->read()) !== false){
        $continue = false;
        foreach($noScann as $arq){ // ERRO NESSA LINHA ***********
            if($d->path.$entry == $arq || $entry == $arq){
                $continue = true;
            }
        }
        if($continue){
            continue;
        }
        if(is_dir($dir.'/'.$entry)){
            $files[] = $d->path.$entry.'/';
            $files = array_merge($files, scan($d->path.$entry.'/'));
        }else{
            $files[] = $d->path.$entry;
        }
    }
    $d->close();
    return $files;
}
var_dump($noScann); // VAR_DUMP ******************
// Resto do arquivo irrelevante
```

O problema é na variavel noScann, que é onde eu declaro as pastas pra não escanear. Como perceberam, é um array, e eu crio ele fora da função, e dentro da função eu chamo com **global $noScann**.

O var_dump dentro da função sempre retorna null, e fora da função retorna os valores certos, é como se eu não tivesse chamado ele dentro da função como global.

Se fosse um erro normal eu nem teria pedido ajuda, eu pesquisei muito mas não achei. Oque eu acho muito estranho é que só dá esse erro quando eu chamo o arquivo dentro da função body() do lib.php, e quando eu acesso o arquivo diretamente (http://.../lib.php) ele não dá erro algum, funciona perfeitamente.

Agradeço desde já qualquer tentativa de me ajudar.
Obs.: Primeiro post aq no stackoverflow, qualquer coisa de errado me corrijam

Comment: Nâo é mais simples passar `$noScann` para a funçãr scan() do que declarar ela como global?

Comment: não testei o motivo de não funcionar o acesso global a variável $noScann.. mas entendi que o motivo de uso é evitar scanear os caminhos especificos no array $noScann. Se for o caso, descomplique e passe como parâmetro. Com isso eliminará um problema.  Outro ponto é o uso de   foreach($noScann as $arq) .. Acho desnecessário.. poderia apenas fazer uso do in_array().

Comment: Como @rray disse, passei `$noScann` para a função e deu certo, obrigado mesmo cara.

Comment: E na verdade eu não conhecia o in_array() @DanielOmine, vou modificar e usar ele, bem mais simples e pode até poupar memória pelo que vi